# CSS: no se pinta el fondo por completo

Tags: css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fondo animado no se adapta al 100% de la pantalla. Cuando cambio `height:100%` por `100vh` se repite dos veces la animación exageradamente.

Uso `bootstrap` y cosas de `angular/form`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
/*Arreglar pixeles*/
section {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #291f2e, #3b2e42, #423549, #61516b,  #423549, #3b2e42, #291f2e);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 3s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}


.access{
    padding:50px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    margin:75px;
    background-color: #3b2e42;
}

h2 {
    color:#fa4347;
    text-align: center;
}

.button{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
button{
    background-color: #fa4347;
    color: #423549;
    border-style:none; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #ff5a5c;
    color: #423549;
    border-style:none; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="button">
      <a routerLink="/"><button>Volver</button></a>
    </div>
  <article>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="access">
        <h2>INICIAR SESIÓN</h2>
        <app-login-input></app-login-input>
      </div>
      <div class="access">
        <h2>REGISTRARSE</h2>
        <app-register-input></app-register-input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
<section>
```

Cuando inspecciono elemento no me toma toda la pagina, solo lo que esta dentro del contenedor, pero no se como hacer que abarque toda la pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes intentar cambiar el contenedor que va tener la imagen de fondo, si la necesitas que te abarque todo el contenkdo de la pagina, puedes probar colocandola en el <body>? tambien puedes probar utilizar alguna propiedad como el background-size: 100%, o cover, para evitar que el fondo se replique que es el comportamiento por defecto o utilizar la propiedad, background-repeat: no-repeat

Answer (score 2):

Basta con agregar la animación a la etiqueta `body` en lugar de hacerlo solo a la etiqueta `section`.

```css
body{
  all: unset;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #291f2e, #3b2e42, #423549, #61516b, #423549, #3b2e42, #291f2e);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 3s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.access {
  padding: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  margin: 75px;
  background-color: #3b2e42;
}

h2 {
  color: #fa4347;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #fa4347;
  color: #423549;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ff5a5c;
  color: #423549;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="button">
      <a routerLink="/"><button>Volver</button></a>
    </div>
    <article>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="access">
          <h2>INICIAR SESIÓN</h2>
          <app-login-input></app-login-input>
        </div>
        <div class="access">
          <h2>REGISTRARSE</h2>
          <app-register-input></app-register-input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  <section>
</body>
```

Comment: no me lo permite. Quizá sea porque uso angular. El error que aparece es "Hash: 5182bc7de203f4c7 - Time: 220ms

Error: src/app/components/login/login.component.html:19:10 - error NG5002: Unexpected closing tag "body". It may happen 
when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags

19 <section></body>
            ~~~~~~~

  src/app/components/login/login.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~
× Failed to compile."

Comment: El error lo que te está indicando es que tienes dos etiquetas de cierre `</body>`. Revisa tu código y asegurate de que tengas solo una etiqueta de apertura `<body>` y de cierre `</body>`.

Comment: ahh es que mi angular viene con un index.html con un body que no voy a poder borrar ):

Comment: Prueba con `body{ all: unset;}`. Edité la respuesta con el ejemplo.

Comment: no funcionó. me sale el mismo error